# How to get the audio stream from PJSIP when there is no audio hardware device

Tags: sip, audio-streaming, pjsip

I want to use PJSIP's C API to record the incoming audio to a file on a machine with no hardware sound device .

I'm unsure about the details, but the sparse documentation for PJSIP suggests it should be 
possible through the `pjsua_set_null_snd_dev()` call.

In the fully functioning (Windows biased) example below the call `pjmedia_aud_dev_default_param(PJMEDIA_AUD_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_DEV, &param)` returns `PJMEDIA_AUD_INVALID_DEV` in the status.

The code generates this same error on Linux (Ubuntu 14) and Windows 10 when there are no hardware audio devices present.
If there *is* an hardware audio device driver installed the exact same code works fine on both OSes.

I have compiled the PJSIP libraries with `PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_NULL_AUDIO` enabled.
On Linux the presence of the module `snd-dummy` does not help.

How do I get access to the audio data stream from a SIP call after calling `pjsua_set_null_snd_dev()`?

```
#include <pjlib.h>
#include <pjlib-util.h>
#include <pjnath.h>
#include <pjsip.h>
#include <pjsip_ua.h>
#include <pjsip_simple.h>
#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>
#include <pjmedia.h>
#include <pjmedia-codec.h>
#include <pj/log.h>
#include <pj/os.h>

    int main(int, char **)
    {
    // Create pjsua first! 
            pj_status_t status = pjsua_create();
            if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"pjsua_create error\n");
                return -1;
            }

    // Init pjsua 
            pjsua_config cfg;
            pjsua_logging_config log_cfg;

            pjsua_config_default(&cfg);

            pjsua_logging_config_default(&log_cfg);
            log_cfg.console_level = 4;

            status = pjsua_init(&cfg, &log_cfg, NULL);
            if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"pjsua_init error\n");
                return -1;
            }


    // Proactively list known audio devices so we are sure there are NONE
            pjmedia_aud_dev_info info[64];
            unsigned info_count = 64;
            pjsua_enum_aud_devs(info, &info_count);

            fprintf(stderr,"Listing known sound devices, total of [%u]\n", info_count);
            for (unsigned i = 0; i<info_count; ++i)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Name [%s]", info[i].name);
            }

    // Add transport
            pjsua_transport_config tcfg;
            pjsua_transport_id trans_id;
            pjsua_transport_config_default(&tcfg);
            tcfg.port = 5060;
            status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &tcfg, &trans_id);
            if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "pjsua_transport_create error\n");
                return -1;
            }

    // Initialization is done, now start pjsua 
            status = pjsua_start();
            if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "pjsua_start error\n");
                return -1;
            }

    // Set NULL sound
            status = pjsua_set_null_snd_dev();
            if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "pjsua_set_null_snd_dev error");
                return -1;
            }

    // Register to a SIP server by creating SIP account, I happen use use Asterisk 
            pjsua_acc_id acc_id;
            fprintf(stderr, "Setting up SIP server registration\n");
            {
                pjsua_acc_config cfg;
                pjsua_acc_config_default(&cfg);
                cfg.id = pj_str("sip:6001@10.0.0.21");
                cfg.reg_uri = cfg.id; // same as ID
                cfg.cred_count = 1;

                cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str("*");
                cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("digest"); 
                cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str("6001");
                cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
                cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str("teddy");

                status = pjsua_acc_add(&cfg, PJ_TRUE, &acc_id);
                if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "pjsua_acc_add error\n");
                    return -1;
                }
            }

            fprintf(stderr, "Waiting for SIP server registration to complete....\n");

            Sleep(2000); // sleep 2 seconds

    // Call extension 9 on my Asterisk server at 10.0.0.21:5060
            pj_str_t sip_target(pj_str("sip:9@10.0.0.21"));
            fprintf(stderr, "Making call to [%s]\n", sip_target.ptr);

            pjsua_call_id call_id;
            status = pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &sip_target, 0, NULL, NULL, &call_id);
            if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "pjsua_call_make_call error\n");
                return -1;
            }

            pj_pool_t * pool = nullptr;
            pjmedia_port * wav = nullptr;
            pjmedia_aud_stream *strm = nullptr;
            pool = pj_pool_create(pjmedia_aud_subsys_get_pool_factory(), "wav-audio", 1000, 1000, NULL);

            if (nullptr == pool)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Pool creation failed\n");
                return -1;
            }

    // 8kHz, single channel 16bit MS WAV format file
            status = pjmedia_wav_writer_port_create(pool, "test.wav", 8000, 1, 320, 16, PJMEDIA_FILE_WRITE_PCM, 0, &wav);
            if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error creating WAV file\n");
                return -1;
            }

            pjmedia_aud_param param; 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // FAILURE HERE : This is the function call which returns PJMEDIA_AUD_INVALID_DEV
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            status = pjmedia_aud_dev_default_param(PJMEDIA_AUD_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_DEV, &param); 
            if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) 
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "pjmedia_aud_dev_default_param()");
                return -1;
            }

            param.dir = PJMEDIA_DIR_CAPTURE;
            param.clock_rate = PJMEDIA_PIA_SRATE(&wav->info);
            param.samples_per_frame = PJMEDIA_PIA_SPF(&wav->info);
            param.channel_count = PJMEDIA_PIA_CCNT(&wav->info);
            param.bits_per_sample = PJMEDIA_PIA_BITS(&wav->info);

            status = pjmedia_aud_stream_create(&param, &test_rec_cb, &test_play_cb, wav, &strm);
            if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the sound stream");
                return -1;
            }

            status = pjmedia_aud_stream_start(strm);
            if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error starting the sound device");
                return -1;
            }

    // Spend some time allowing the called party to pick up and recording to proceed
            Sleep(10000); // sleep 10 seconds

    // Clean up code omitted
    return 0;
    }
```

Apologies to the pure of heart for the mix of C and C++ above.

Comment: pjsua_set_null_snd_dev() is used to disconnect tha audio stream in pjsip. It MUST be used while ending the call

Comment: @JimmyNJ I'm interested in the solution to this problem if you could post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by loading the Alsa module [snd-dummy](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-dummy).

Look in `/lib/modules/YOUR_KERNEL_VERSION/modules.dep` if its mentioned.

If you have it then load it with `modprobe snd-dummy`

Otherwise recompile your Kernel to include it as a module or follow the installation in the link above.

Comment: Nope, sorry this is doesn't work, I tried the modules issue. And a kernel recompile is not possible.

Comment: Do you have Alsa support enabled when compiling the library? I set `#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_ALSA` to 1 in `pjmedia/include/pjmedia-audiodev/config.h` and `pjlib/include/pj/config_site_sample.h` also my autoconf options include --enable-sound. Source: https://imsj.dev/blog/pjsip-on-raspberry-pi-via-alsa/

Comment: I solved it too and just posted here how I did it. I thought you didn't solve it as there was no answer to it on here?!